# (Done) Request to reopen working remotely from another country than UK

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question [How long can I work remotely from Italy if my workplace is UK without me/my employer incurring taxing issues?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/162776/how-long-can-i-work-remotely-from-italy-if-my-workplace-is-uk-without-me-my-empl) was closed due to *"Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies ... Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals"*. I believe this is incorrect, as I've answered the question with relevant details from the standard UK tax guidelines.

It doesn't come under a legal issue, as this is more a tax question issue and can be understood by reading the UK tax guidelines, and it's not company specific policies as this is the same for any UK employee. This is a question that can and will affect many people across the UK and is not specific to just this user.

Comment: vtro.... need a couple more

Comment: Great answer on the relevant UK law but the Italian law is missing. As written I would close this as well since the interaction of UK and Italian law for this specific situation is quite likely to be too specific and difficulty to answer without extensive knowledge of both legal domains. Exhaustive answers are not impossible, but improbable. (Edit: maybe it's ok if it's just "how many days") The bigger point is that it probably doesn't need to cover both. I'd edit this to focus purely on the UK aspects of the law for those working outside the UK. OP can post about the Italian side if needed.

Comment: VTRO as well, two more needed

Comment: @Lilienthal  As someone who works with Italian companies and knows parts of their tax law, that's a whole different ball game that I'd never consider discussing. Even they don't know how it works half the time, so I agree it should stay UK centric

Comment: @Draken I've made that edit (but might need another pass by someone) and cast a 4th and binding reopen.

Comment: "this is more a tax question issue" - is The Workplace the proper forum for asking international tax questions? It wouldn't seem to be.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It is when it's employment tax, this is a tax levied depending on your employment status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post is now open again, and was also edited to better shape.